# Creating a dataframe column with strings in random spots

Tags: r, string

I am trying to figure out how to make one of my columns in my dataframe certain words that are randomly generated and have replacement. For example, I would like a column of length 20 with the words dog, cat, mouse, pig in any random order.

I know that for integers you would use the sample function so I am not sure how to do it with strings

I tried using sample (with the animal names as strings), size=20, replace= f but that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Your replacement is set to FALSE, and the total number of animal names is smaller than your sample size. Try set `replace = TRUE`

```
sample(c("pig", "dog", "cat", "mouse"), 20, replace = TRUE)

[1] "cat"   "pig"   "dog"   "dog"   "mouse" "dog"   "mouse" "cat"   "dog"   "cat"   "cat"   "mouse" "pig"   "mouse" "mouse" "mouse" "cat"   "mouse"
[19] "pig"   "dog"
```